# Hyperswarm: How to use node.holepunch()

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use the [hyperswarm](https://github.com/hyperswarm/dht/#nodeholepunchpeer-callback) js API to do hole punching to my friend's computer.

But I cannot figure out where to obtain the parameters required for the method.

```js
node.holepunch(peer, [callback])
```

From the docs,

> peer should be a { host, port, referrer: { host, port } }, where referrer should be the host and port of the DHT node who told you about this peer.

1. I guess the host/port are the public ports that are visible externally on the NAT? Is there an API in hyperswarm to obtain this, or do I have to obtain this using a signaling server myself?
2. How to get the host/port of a DHT? Is it the `nodes.bootstrapNodes` ?

```
[ { host: 'bootstrap1.hyperdht.org', port: 49737 },
  { host: 'bootstrap2.hyperdht.org', port: 49737 },
  { host: 'bootstrap3.hyperdht.org', port: 49737 } ]
```

Comment: Can you share details of code and what you have already done?

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap nodes will not help you to holepunch, but will instead give you the IP addresses of other nodes participating in the DHT. You can then use one of those peers to holepunch.

The holepunching logic of hyperswarm appears to be contained in [dht-rpc](https://github.com/mafintosh/dht-rpc) if you need further reference.